# What is the "Flow_type" attribute in Microsoft's Azure ARM Template for Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

It's described as a non-required field, but it's an enum (without any other listed options) and the description is vague: Used by the Application Insights system to determine what kind of flow this component was created by. This is to be set to 'Bluefield' when creating/updating a component via the REST API. - Bluefield.

My rule of thumb is don't include anything extra (KISS) that doesn't break my application, but if there's some benefit I can get out of it, I'd like to know. Thanks!

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.insights/components?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json

Comment: I see Bluefield and Redfield as the values. Seems Redfield is something ancient.

Answer (score 3):

`Flow_Type` and `Request_Source` Do not have any effect in the current version, and they might be deprecated in future versions of App Insights API